# Access current environment name for a NextJS app running on amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have added a few tables on DynamoDB using the `amplify add storage` command.

But the table has a suffix that is the environment name (dev, prod, etc).

How can I access the environment name on my NextJS backend so I can suffix the DynamoDB table name on my code ?

Or there is another way to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 0):

Amplify automatically creates DynamoDB tables (and also AppSync queries, etc) to match your current Amplify environment. When you create a new environment (eg, 'dev'), the Amplify will automatically create duplicate 'prod' tables, that will perform the same as you 'dev' tables. I'm guessing in your case, you won't need to access environment variables.

If you are using AppSync/GraphQL to make calls, then you can use Amplify's built in dynamic env features here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/function/#usage

For example, you could set up a custom Lambda function to update your DynamoDB. You could then set up an AppSync call to that Lambda in your `schema.graphql` file.

There are some cases where you may need to access your environment variables. You can either set them up manually in `.env.local`, or possibly easier to run a query in your NextJS javascript to determine the current domain:

```js
const origin =
  typeof window !== "undefined" && window.location.origin
    ? window.location.origin
    : "";
console.log(origin); // "https://dev.<>.amplifyapp.com"
```

An better solution would be to follow [this Amplify documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#setting-env-vars), except I've tried it and it doesn't work.

I get this in the left nav panel. I've explored each one and no sign of the described Environment Variables section:
[image]

It describes accessing/updating env vars [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#amplify-console-environment-variables), but apparently you can only find/use this feature if you've connected your Amplify app to Github first. (It would have been nice if the docs had clarified this!)